# How do I serialize a relationship as 'ID' instead of embedding the entire struct?

Tags: go, orm, go-gorm

I specified the following models

```
type Item struct {
    gorm.Model
    Name     string
    Category ItemCategory
}

type ItemCategory struct {
    gorm.Model
    Name string
}
```

After serializing an Item, I want:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Item name",
  "category_id": 1
}
```

Instead of embedding the entire category. Is there a way to customize the serializer?

Comment: This looks to be a database model, not a DTO

Answer (score 0):

There are different interfaces for serializing/deserializing regarding your usecase, but if you are looking for JSON, this might help:

https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-go-client/serialization#JSON

Basically you need to implement `func (j JSON) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error)` which becomes something like this:

```golang
func (i Item) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
   m = map[string]any{
      "id": i.Id,
      "name": i.Name,
      "category_id": i.Category.Id,
   }

   return json.Marshal(m)
}
```

Aside this and on a general **NOTE** do not mix database models with DTO you pass around between functions or want to return to user, always separate them.